# Juego de triqui

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un juego de Triqui, el problema es cuando alguno de los dos gana, el juego sigue. Necesito que apenas uno gane, se detenga hasta que le den al botón reiniciar.
Aquí el código:

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TRIQUI</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tictactoe.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row ">
       <div class="col-md-3"></div>
       <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                      <h3>TRIQUI</h3>
                      <div id="tictactoe"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3"></div>
   </div>

  </div> 
<script src="tictactoe.js">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

***JS***

```
var turno="o";
var cantidadOpciones=3;
var Juego="tictactoe";

CrearComponentesJuego();
$( ".pieza" ).click(function() {
$(this).val(turno);
cotejar(); 
turno=(turno=="o")?"x":"o";
$('#turnoDisplay').val(turno);
});
function cotejar(){
for(i=1;i<=cantidadOpciones;i++){
for(j=1;j<=cantidadOpciones;j++){
    fila=i;columna=j;

    contadorTotalFilas=1;
    contadorTotalcolumnas=1;
    contadorDiagonal=1;
    contadorDiagonalInversa=1;
    contadorTurnos=0;

    $( ".pieza" ).each(function( index ) {
        elid=$( this ).attr('id');

        if((elid.charAt(0)==fila)&&($( this ).val()==turno)){
            contadorTotalFilas++;   
            if(contadorTotalFilas==(cantidadOpciones+1)){campeon(); }
        }

        if((elid.charAt(1)==columna)&&($( this ).val()==turno)){
            contadorTotalcolumnas++;    
            if(contadorTotalcolumnas==(cantidadOpciones+1)) {campeon();}
        }
        if((elid.charAt(1)==elid.charAt(0))&&($( this ).val()==turno)){
            contadorDiagonal++;
            if(contadorDiagonal==(cantidadOpciones+1)){campeon();}
        }
      valorTotaldiagonal= parseInt(elid.charAt(1))+parseInt(elid.charAt(0));
        if(((valorTotaldiagonal)==(cantidadOpciones+1)) &&($( this 
     ).val()==turno)){
             contadorDiagonalInversa++;
              if(contadorDiagonalInversa==(cantidadOpciones+1)){campeon();   
  }
        }
        if($(this).val()!="-"){contadorTurnos++;
            if(contadorTurnos==(cantidadOpciones*cantidadOpciones)) 
   {TerminarJuego();}
        }
        if(contadorTurnos==9){
            Reiniciar();
        }

     });
    }}
    }
    function TerminarJuego(){
    $("#alertMensaje").html("Juego terminado");
    $(".alert").show('slow');
    $( "#iniciar" ).removeClass( "disabled" );
    }
    function Reiniciar(){
     $(".alert").hide('slow');
    contadorTotalFilas=1;
    contadorTotalcolumnas=1;
    contadorDiagonal=1;
    contadorDiagonalInversa=1;
    contadorTurnos=0;
    $( ".pieza" ).each(function( index ) { $( this ).val('-');});
    $( "#iniciar" ).addClass( "disabled" );        
    }
    function campeon(){
    $("#alertMensaje").html('Ganador <strong><input class="ganador btn btn- 
    primary btn-lg" type="button" value="'+turno+'"></strong>');
    $(".alert").show('slow');
    $( "#iniciar" ).removeClass( "disabled" );
    }
    function cerrarAlert(){
    $(".alert").hide('slow');
    $( "#iniciar" ).removeClass( "disabled" );
    Reiniciar();
    }
    function CrearComponentesJuego(){
    $("#"+Juego).append('<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-warning 
    collapse"><button type="button" class="close" 
    onclick="cerrarAlert()">×</button><div id="alertMensaje"></div></div>');

    for(i=1;i<=cantidadOpciones;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=cantidadOpciones;j++){
    $("#"+Juego).append( "<input class='pieza btn btn-primary btn-lg' 
    type='button' value='-' id='"+i+j+"'/>" );
    }
    $("#"+Juego).append( "<hr style='  margin: 7px;'/>" );
    }$("#"+Juego).append('<br/>');
     $("#"+Juego).append('<span class=" well"><strong>Turno:</strong> <input 
    class="btn btn-warning" id="turnoDisplay" type="button" value="o"></span>');
    $("#"+Juego).append('<br/>');
    $("#"+Juego).append('<br/>');
    $("#"+Juego).append('<input type="button" id="iniciar" 
    onclick="Reiniciar()" value="Reiniciar" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg 
    disabled"/>');
    }
```

***CSS***

```
.pieza{border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;width: 70px;height:70px;margin-left: 15px;margin-right: 15px;}
    .pieza[value="x"]{color: #ffffff;background-color: #4caf50;}
    .pieza[value="o"]{ color: #ffffff;background-color: #9c27b0;}
    .ganador{border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;width: 70px;height:70px;margin-left: 15px;margin-right: 15px;}
    .ganador[value="x"]{color: #ffffff;background-color: #4caf50;}
    .ganador[value="o"]{ color: #ffffff;background-color: #9c27b0;}
```

Comment: Carlos, para hacer una pregunta válida no solo has de mostrar el codigo que tienes si no tu problema concreto. Has de intentarlo y explicarnos por qué no lo has conseguido o qué errores tienes. Decir "necesito que" no es suficiente. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lograr lo que deseas sólo hacen falta algunos cambios en tu js.

- Cuando el número de turnos se agotan debes llamar al *terminarJuego()*
- Cuando alguien resulta ganador deberás bloquear todos los botones mediante la función **.attr('disabled', false)** con un forEach, que ya has implementado
- Y además en tu función **reiniciar()** deberás volver a activar los botones con la misma propiedad que te indiqué:

  $( ".pieza" ).each(function( index ) { $( this ).val('-'); $(this).attr('disabled', false)});

**Te dejo el script para que lo puedas ver:**

```js
var turno = "o";
var cantidadOpciones = 3;
var Juego = "tictactoe";

CrearComponentesJuego();
$(".pieza").click(function() {
  $(this).val(turno);
  cotejar();
  turno = (turno == "o") ? "x" : "o";
  $('#turnoDisplay').val(turno);
});

function cotejar() {
  for (i = 1; i <= cantidadOpciones; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= cantidadOpciones; j++) {
      fila = i;
      columna = j;
      contadorTotalFilas = 1;
      contadorTotalcolumnas = 1;
      contadorDiagonal = 1;
      contadorDiagonalInversa = 1;
      contadorTurnos = 0;
      $(".pieza").each(function(index) {
        elid = $(this).attr('id');
        if ((elid.charAt(0) == fila) && ($(this).val() == turno)) {
          contadorTotalFilas++;
          if (contadorTotalFilas == (cantidadOpciones + 1)) {
            campeon();
          }
        }

        if ((elid.charAt(1) == columna) && ($(this).val() == turno)) {
          contadorTotalcolumnas++;
          if (contadorTotalcolumnas == (cantidadOpciones + 1)) {
            campeon();
          }
        }
        if ((elid.charAt(1) == elid.charAt(0)) && ($(this).val() == turno)) {
          contadorDiagonal++;
          if (contadorDiagonal == (cantidadOpciones + 1)) {
            campeon();
          }
        }
        valorTotaldiagonal = parseInt(elid.charAt(1)) + parseInt(elid.charAt(0));
        if (((valorTotaldiagonal) == (cantidadOpciones + 1)) && ($(this).val() == turno)) {
          contadorDiagonalInversa++;
          if (contadorDiagonalInversa == (cantidadOpciones + 1)) {
            campeon();
          }
        }
        if ($(this).val() != "-") {
          contadorTurnos++;
          if (contadorTurnos == (cantidadOpciones * cantidadOpciones)) {
            TerminarJuego();
          }
        }
        if (contadorTurnos == 9) {
          TerminarJuego();
        }

      });
    }
  }
}

function TerminarJuego() {
  $("#alertMensaje").html("Juego terminado");
  $(".alert").show('slow');
  $("#iniciar").removeClass("disabled");
  $(".pieza").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
  }); //
}

function Reiniciar() {
  $(".alert").hide('slow');
  contadorTotalFilas = 1;
  contadorTotalcolumnas = 1;
  contadorDiagonal = 1;
  contadorDiagonalInversa = 1;
  contadorTurnos = 0;
  $(".pieza").each(function(index) {
    $(this).val('-');
    $(this).attr('disabled', false)
  }); //
  $("#iniciar").addClass("disabled");
}

function campeon() {
  $("#alertMensaje").html('Ganador <strong><input class="ganador btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" value="' + turno + '"></strong>');
  $(".alert").show('slow');
  $("#iniciar").removeClass("disabled");
  $(".pieza").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
  });
}

function cerrarAlert() {
  $(".alert").hide('slow');
  $("#iniciar").removeClass("disabled");
  Reiniciar();
}

function CrearComponentesJuego() {
  $("#" + Juego).append('<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-warning collapse"><button type="button" class="close" onclick="cerrarAlert()">×</button><div id="alertMensaje"></div></div>');

  for (i = 1; i <= cantidadOpciones; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= cantidadOpciones; j++) {
      $("#" + Juego).append("<input class='pieza btn btn-primary btn-lg' type='button' value='-' id='" + i + j + "'/>");
    }
    $("#" + Juego).append("<hr style='  margin: 7px;'/>");
  }
  $("#" + Juego).append('<br/>');
  $("#" + Juego).append('<span class=" well"><strong>Turno:</strong> <input class="btn btn-warning" id="turnoDisplay" type="button" value="o"></span>');
  $("#" + Juego).append('<br/>');
  $("#" + Juego).append('<br/>');
  $("#" + Juego).append('<input type="button" id="iniciar" onclick="Reiniciar()" value="Reiniciar" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg    disabled"/>');
}
```

Comment: Bueno la solución a tu pregunta está hecha,  para lo que tu mencionas sólo faltaría deshabilitar los botones cuando se seleccionan, en la misma parte donde pones 'X' o 'O', esto evitaría que se sobre escriba las "jugadas" realizadas. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: hola Luis, gracias por responder pero las preguntas que no tienen lo intentado no deben ser respondidas porque se consideran de baja calidad. Estarías haciendole la tarea a alguien que no se ha esforzado, aparentemente, y hasta que no la edite con sus problemas concretos no podemos ayudarle. Un saludo